# Lyaponuv stability condition of linear systems for homogenous P in V(x) = x^T P x

Tags: control-engineering, mathematics, optimal-control, stability, linear-systems

I am currently learning about using Lyaponuv functions to find Linear Matrix Inequalities (LMIs) as conditions for stability of a linear time invariant system.

i.e.
$$
\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)
$$
is stable if there exists a function $V(x)$ such that $V(x)>0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $V(0) = 0$ **and** $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ for all $x \neq 0$

Generally we have learned to do this with a quadratic Lyapunov function $V(x) = x^TPx$ where $P\succ 0$ and $A^TP + PA \prec 0 $, but I just came across this footnote which I am struggling to understand.

[image]

The $P$ matrix also has to be symmetric which I am not sure why is true.

When performing convex optimisation on systems with Lyaponuv functions our lectures sometimes use the first LMIs i.e. $P \succ 0$ and other times we use $P \succeq I $ and I am not sure when and why the difference arises.

Comment: Little side note: it has to be V(x)>0, not <

Comment: @OpticalResonator thanks! I've corrected it

Comment: @AJN thank you, that does answer my question as to why $P$ needs to be symmetric. And yes I do believe $(P-I)\succeq 0 $ is the stricter condition but I'm not sure why or when we would use it.

Comment: @AJN I don't really have a proof for it which is why I was confused. It only says due to homogeneity in $P$, the $P \succ 0$ and $A^TP + PA \prec 0 $ conditions turn into $P \succeq I $ and $A^TP + PA \preceq I $. Any idea what homogeneity in $P$ could be referring to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126407/discussion-between-ajn-and-chryron).